# First Page Table Position Shifts

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, printing

Can anyone suggest a reason for the table changing position on the first page using this html?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>testfile</title>
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
<style type="text/css">
Table {
    page-break-after: always;
}
</style>
</head><body>
<table width="100%">
<tr><td width="30%"><i>Group:</i></td>
<td width="70%">Test Group 1</td></tr>
<tr><td><i>Title:</i></td>
<td><b>Test Title 1</b></td></tr>
<tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
</table><br/>
<table width="100%">
<tr><td width="30%"><i>Group:</i></td>
<td width="70%">Test Group 2</td></tr>
<tr><td><i>Title:</i></td>
<td><b>Test Title 2</b></td></tr>
<tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
</table><br/>
<table width="100%">
<tr><td width="30%"><i>Group:</i></td>
<td width="70%">Test Group 3</td></tr>
<tr><td><i>Title:</i></td>
<td><b>Test Title 3</b></td></tr>
<tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
</body></html>
```

When you do a print preview in IE9, the table on the first page is in a different position (higher) than any of the tables on the other pages.

Can anyone see a reason for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This style causes page breaks after each table:

```
Table {
  page-break-after: always;
}
```

After the first and second table, you have a `<br/>` tag, which adds a blank line.

Therefore, your second and third tables are being pushed down by the `<br/>`.

You can correct this by either removing the `<br/>` tags *or* by adding a `<br/>` tag before the first table.

Note that `br` is a [void element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#void-element), so the "/" symbol isn't needed.  You'll usually see it as simply `<br>`.

**Update**

You may also need to add this style:

```
body {
  margin: 0px;
}
```

Otherwise, the margin may be applied on the first page only.  This is *not* true for IE11, but it *is* true for Chrome and apparently also true for IE9.

Comment: ah yes, I hadn't noticed them!!  Unfortunately after removing them, it is still the same.  I've also noticed that I'd missed a </table> from the end too but adding that didn't help (not that I'd expect it to cure the position problem!!)

Comment: That fixes the problem for IE11, but I don't have an IE9 installation to test it on.  You could also try removing the margin from the body:  `body {margin: 0px;}`

Comment: Great, that seems to vary from browser to browser.  I've updated my answer.